# How can I set and retain font size of the solarized-theme?

Tags: fonts, themes

I like the solarized (light) theme in emacs but i have a 27" mac so the font is too small.

I know I can enlarge with C-x C-+ but I do not know how to set the font size and retain that setting so I need not change manually.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ain't no expert on fonts. Let me know if this works for you (It's supposed to set font size to be 20):

```lisp
(let ((fsize 20)   ;; font size
      (fs (font-spec :name (frame-parameter nil 'font))))
  (font-put fs :size fsize)
  (set-frame-font fs nil t)
  (let ((new-font (frame-parameter nil 'font))
        (current-default (assq 'font default-frame-alist)))
    (if current-default
        (setcdr current-default new-font)
      (push (cons 'font new-font) default-frame-alist))))
```

Comment: most helpful, it works perfectly!!!! thank you